# XHTML transitional self closing tags

Tags: xhtml

I am using the

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
```

Doctype and notice that I'm being suggested elements such as

```
<P /> instead of <p> </p>
```

In my eclipse IDE. Is this just a self closing tag? is the capital letter a standard of somesort?

Comment: No, `<P />` is not valid XHTML. If your software suggests changing <p> to <P> in an XHTML environment, that's wrong. Dump it. Or at the very least, don't listen to its suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, `<p />` is a self-closing tag for `<p></p>`, and is **valid** in XHTML (but not HTML5).

Every browser that supports XHTML supports the self-closing syntax for [**every tag**](https://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/#h-4.3):

> Elements that are declared in the DTD as EMPTY can have an end tag or can use empty element shorthand (see Empty Elements).

Having said that, a self-closing paragraph makes no sense.

It's important to note that XHTML elements [**must**](https://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/#h-4.2) be written in lower-case:

> XHTML documents must use lower case for all HTML element and attribute names. This difference is necessary because XML is case-sensitive e.g. `<li>` and `<LI>` are different tags.

It's also important to note that the XHTML `doctype` is **outdated** [as of **2012**](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/149843/282231). I **strongly** suggest switching to HTML 5 instead.

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: `<p />` (at least with a lowercase p) is valid and well-formed XML, but it's recommended to write `<p></p>` anyway, for interchangeability reasons. Only void elements should really be written with a self-closing tag.